# JQuery: content loading doesn't wait for animation to be finished

Tags: jquery, load, slidetoggle

```
$("#clickme").click(
            function(){
                $(this).slideToggle(1000);
                $(this).load("MYTEXT.txt");
                $(this).slideToggle(1000);
            }   
        )
```

I want the new content of my HTML element to be displayed ONLY after the first animations is finished. What happens in this code is, it first slides up, and slides down with new content, but the new content is shown before the slide up effect is done!

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#clickme").click( 
            function(){ 
                $(this).slideToggle(1000, function () {
                    $(this).load("MYTEXT.txt", function () {
                        $(this).slideToggle(1000);
                    });
                });     
            }    
        )
```

To get things to happen after eachother, you can use callbacks to run code only after the previous function has run (which is very useful for animations and AJAX calls).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to chain them as callbacks

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle(1000, function(){
        $(this).load("MYTEXT.txt", function(){
            $(this).slideToggle(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#clickme").click(
            function(){
                $(this).slideToggle(1000).load("MYTEXT.txt").slideToggle(1000);
            }   
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
      $(this).slideToggle(1000, function() {
          $(this).load("MYTEXT.txt", function() {
              $(this).slideToggle(1000);
           });
      });
});
```